# Why didn't my WPF window show up even with correct syntax?

Tags: c#, wpf

Here's the code

```
<Window x:Class="WpfTest.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:BobuxNotifierWpfTest"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="test app" Height="450" Width="800"
        Background="#fff0f6">
    <Grid Width="390" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,10,0,10" Background="#ffe8f2">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="400*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="30*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Label FontSize="35" FontWeight="DemiBold" FontFamily="Fonts\Halyard Text Regular" Margin="10,0,10,10">
            heading
        </Label>
        <TextBlock FontSize="18" FontFamily="Fonts\Halyard Text Regular" FontWeight="DemiBold" Foreground="#633247" Margin="15,65,0,0" TextWrapping="WrapWithOverflow">
            <Label>first body line</Label>
            <Label>second body line</Label>
            <Label FontSize="12" Margin="0,20,0,0">footer</Label>
        </TextBlock>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

this code didn't give me any errors but when I run it all I got was

> ========== Build: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========

I also didn't do anything to the Main() class or the xaml.cs file

any help lol

Comment: show contents of `app.xaml`

Comment: Did you specify the window as `StartupUri` in `App.xaml` like this: `<Application ... StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">` or did you create a new instance and call `Show` in `App.xaml.cs`?

Comment: @thatguy oops I'm fairly new to wpf so I just deleted that file thinking it's useless. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Application` is usually one of the most important classes in your WPF project, not useless.

> Encapsulates a Windows Presentation Foundation application. [...]
>
> You can implement an `Application` using markup, markup and code-behind, or code. If `Application`is implemented with markup, whether markup or markup and code-behind, **the markup file must be configured as an Microsoft build engine (MSBuild) `ApplicationDefinition` item**.

You have to tell WPF which window should be shown on startup using [`StartupUri`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.application.startupuri?f1url=%3FappId%3DDev16IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Windows.Application.StartupUri);k(VS.XamlEditor)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=windowsdesktop-6.0).

```
<Application x:Class="WpfTest.MainWindow"
             ...
             StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">
```

Another way is adding a [`Startup`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.application.startup?f1url=%3FappId%3DDev16IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Windows.Application.Startup);k(VS.XamlEditor)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=windowsdesktop-6.0) event handler and creating your window there.

```
<Application WpfTest.MainWindow""
             ...
             Startup="OnStartup">
```

```
public partial class App : Application
{
   private void OnStartup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
   {
      new MainWindow().Show();
   }
}
```

That being said, **it is possible** to run a WPF standalone application without an `Application` instance.

> A standalone application does not require an `Application` object; it is possible to implement a custom static entry point method (`Main`) that opens a window without creating an instance of Application.

However, it is in all likelihood not what you want to do since [the application object provides services](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.application?view=windowsdesktop-6.0#remarks) like an application-wide resource dictionary to name just one with a big impact.

> `Application` implements the singleton pattern to provide shared access to its window, property, and resource scope services. [...]
>
> - **Application Lifetime:** Activated, Current, Deactivated, DispatcherUnhandledException, Exit, Run, SessionEnding, Shutdown, ShutdownMode, Startup.
> - **Application-Scope Window, Property, and Resource Management:** FindResource, GetContentStream, GetResourceStream, LoadComponent, MainWindow, Properties, Resources, StartupUri, Windows.
> - **Command-Line Parameter and Exit Code Processing:** Application.Startup, Application.Exit, Application.Shutdown.
> - **Navigation:** FragmentNavigation, LoadCompleted, Navigated, Navigating, NavigationProgress, NavigationStopped, NavigationFailed, SetCookie, GetCookie.